# Calculating the Difference Between Two Values in the Same Column using group by in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table as shown below. I want to do a partition and then subtract the values in the same column and different rows to get the difference using group by.

| id | type | name | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | sale | sam | 2 |
| 2 | sale | sam | 15 |
| 3 | return | lilly | 20 |
| 4 | sale | lilly | 25 |
| 5 | return | sam | 3 |
| 6 | sale | anju | 20 |

And Need to return:

| name | amount |
| --- | --- |
| sam | 14 |
| lilly | 5 |
| anju | 20 |

Comment: How will you get 14 for `sam`  (from `2,15 and 3`)

Comment: Why is anju not -20, since it's a return with no sale?

Comment: @Luuk sam's total sale amount is 15+2=17,return amount is 3,so 17-3=14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sample data is a little suspect but I think you basically need to apply a case expression to your sale *type*:

```
select name,
    Sum(amount * case when type='return' then -1 else 1 end) Amount
from t
group by name;
```